# paginate_links URL

Tags: paginate-links

My code looks like this:

```
paginate_links( 
  array(
   'next_text' => __('>'), 
   'prev_text' => __('<'), 
   'base' => @add_query_arg('page', '%#%'), 
   'format' => '?page=%#%&a='.$a, 
   'total' => ceil($count/$per_page), 
   'current' => $page)
)
```

Everything works perfectly but if I click on for example second page my URL goes to `www.domain.com/something/2/?a=5` instead of `www.domain.com/something/?page=2&a=5`

Is it possible to change it into `www.domain.com/something/?page=2&a=5`?

Comment: Please let us know what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried just that code you can see above, this worked for me on homepage but when I apply this on other page it doesn't work

Comment: I think you want that WordPres don't use pretty permalinks for the pagination links. I think it is not possible. You can disable pretty permalinks in Settings->permalinks, but it a global option. I think that the only way to do it is writting your own pagination function.

Answer (score 1):

Change variable `page` to something else, page is a reserved keyword & whenever in url it found it convert url in to `localhost/wordpress/page/2`